# I have some problem in my code with session and I don't know what is going on?

Tags: php

I am having problem with php session. I have a function that checks if user is logged in

```
       function is_logged_in()  {
                my_session();
           if ($_SEESION['logged_in'] === true )
                {
                    // it is true
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // is not true
                    return false;

                }
                my_session();
            }
```

I  function my_session is as below.

```
    function my_session() {
        $status = session_status();
        if($status == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
            //There is no active session
            session_start();
        }else
            if($status == PHP_SESSION_DISABLED){
                //Sessions are not available
            }else
                if($status == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
                    //Destroy current and start new one
                    session_destroy();
                    session_start();
                }
    }
```

but still it is saying Undefined variable: _SEESION. 
I have putted code in same file where I wants check if user is loggged in and tried starting with session_start() and then ended it with simple session destroy but no luck.

Comment: $_SE**E**SION => $_SE**S**SION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$_SEESION` with `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

just replace this

```
 if ($_SEESION['logged_in'] === true )
```

at this

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] === true )
```